# Getting attributes into link_to from large array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating an application that lists employees and uses a self join to show managers and direct_reports.

In my model I have:

```
has_many :direct_reports, :class_name => "Person", :foreign_key => "manager_id"
belongs_to :manager, :class_name => "Person"
```

In my view I'm trying to have links to all of the direct_reports of an employee where their name (split into fname and lame) comprise the link.

Currently in my view for direct_reports I have the following which is what the Rails guides recommend.

```
<%= @person.direct_reports %>
```

That results in this being generated.

```
    [#<Person id: 3674, fname: "Leland", lname: "Allison", phone: "8474020494", email: 
    "leland.allison@myco.com", ntid: "lalli", address: "3568 Sanders Rd.", city: 
    "Northbrook", state: "IL", zipcode: "60062", country: "USA", suite: nil, column: 
    nil, title: nil, department: nil, created_at: "2013-02-01 19:17:58", updated_at: 
    "2013-02-01 19:17:58", equipment: nil, capacity: nil, latitude: nil, longitude: 
    nil, manager: nil, direct_report: nil, manager_id: 3668>, #<Person id: 3685, fname:
     "Rochelle", lname: "Baldwin", phone: "8474020338", email: "rochelle.baldwin@myco.com",
     ntid: "rbald", address: "3412 Sanders Rd.", city: "Northbrook", state: "IL", 
    zipcode: "60062", country: "USA", suite: nil, column: nil, title: nil, department: 
    nil, created_at: "2013-02-01 19:17:58", updated_at: "2013-02-01 19:17:58", equipment: 
    nil, capacity: nil, latitude: nil, longitude: nil, manager: nil, direct_report: nil,
     manager_id: 3668>, #<Person id: 3692, fname: "Tammy", lname: "Barnett", phone: 
    "8474020275", email: "tammy.barnett@myco.com", ntid: "tbarn", address: "3349 
    Sanders Rd.", city: "Northbrook", state: "IL", zipcode: "60062", country: "USA", 
    suite: nil, column: nil, title: nil, department: nil, created_at: "2013-02-01 19:17:58",
     updated_at: "2013-02-01 19:17:58", equipment: nil, capacity: nil, latitude: nil, 
    longitude: nil, manager: nil, direct_report: nil, manager_id: 3668>]
```

So I'm obviously getting the entire object for each record which is way more than I need.

I've tried putting the following in my view:

```
<% @people.each do |person| %>
  <%= link_to person.lname + ", " + person.fname, person %>
<% end %>
```

But that isn't working. I get a "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass" error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the assignment into @people, you don't show us where you assign into that instance variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined the `@People`, so there is no each. It would be `@person.direct_reports.each`

Comment: Do you mean `@person.direct_reports.each`?

Comment: Changing it to @person.direct_reports.each fixed it. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

You should save the value in any variable and then apply each on it. 
there is no `@people` variable define, Hence `@people` is nil.

Your code will look like this in your controller:

```
@people = @person.direct_reports
```

and in view your code will look like:

```
 <% @people.each do |person| %>
        <%= link_to person.lname + ", " + person.fname, person %>
    <% end %>
```

This will work now

Answer (score 0):

`def people_and_reports(person)
  [person, person.direct_reports.map {|p| people_and_reports(p)}].flatten.uniq
end`

@people = people_and_reports(@person)

Whooops.. just reread question.. this will recursively walk down from a person to all reports and reports of reports.  you probably just need @people = @person.direct_reports